# find 1st non null value from a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, lambda

I use lambda functions like this to pass row values and they work as desired:

```
def get_price(row, source):
    if source == 'cgo':
        return row.price

df_merged['price'] = df_merged.apply(lambda x: get_price(x, 'cgo')
                                               , axis=1)
```

However, now I would like to use a more complication lambda function. So for example, if **df_merged.art = ‘R' and df_merged.ust = 'J'**, then I want to return the **first 2 characters of first non null value from the df_merged.kst** column. I was trying this:

```
def get_id(row, source):
    if source == 'cgo':
        found = False

        if found == False:

            #if row.kst != Null:
            if (row.kst):

                first_kst= row.kst
                logger.debug(f"first_kst : {first_kst}")

                found = True


        if row.art == "R" and row.ust == "J":
            return first_kst[:2]

df_merged['id'] = df_merged.apply(lambda x: get_id(x, 'cgo')
                                               , axis=1)
```

I used a bool value `found` to stop searching when I find the first non null value. Then I returned the stored `first_kst` value when the conditions meet. However, this doesn't work as desired.

In my print logs, I see  `DEBUG | first_kst : nan |` multiple times, even though my print statement is inside the  `if` statement and it should only print once, when the value is not null and the first non value is found. What could be an alternative way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.isnan()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) with the not operator (`~`).

```
import numpy as np

def not_na(array):
    return ~np.isnan(array)

def first_not_na_value(array):
    return list(filter(not_na, array))[0]
```

Example:

```
d= {
    'A':[1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'B':[np.nan, np.nan, 3, 4, np.nan, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'C':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

first_not_na_value(df.A) #outputs 1.0
first_not_na_value(df.B) #outputs 3.0
first_not_na_value(df.B) #outputs 1.0
```